# Python+Flask. Не загружаются прямые ссылки в img src. Как исправить?

Tags: python, flask

Всем привет.

Набросал скрипт для flask и html скрипт к нему

В шаблоне есть тег img куда передается в src ссылка на изображение из скрипта.

В шаблоне:

```
<img src="{{ score[2] }}" height="200px">
```

В браузере получаем:

```
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c4946/u299074/-6/y_a7ba6cd3.jpg" height="200px">
```

В браузере пишется не удалось загрузить изображение, если просто скорпировать и открыть ссылку то всё ок, открывается.

Как это исправить? Почему не отображает если все есть?

Спасибо заранее

Comment: Блокировщики рекламы в браузере есть? Попробуй отключить

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего браузер блокирует изображение из стороннего ресурса по соображениям приватности. Здесь есть несколько способов получения доступа:

1. Включить Cross-Origin на сайте с которого вы пытаетесь загрузить изображение
2. Проксировать ссылку к изображению через свой сервер, тоесть сделать некий скрипт, который будет стучаться к серверу ВК, получать изображение и отдавать на свой фронтенд (в данном случае думаю это единственный выход)